# "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE" in hibernate with Spring 3, maven, JPA, c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, postgresql, maven-2

Problem:

Hibernate is not executing queries correctly. It errors with a problem that appears to be related to slf4j but using any recommended fixes don't seem to work.

I've tried various combinations of variable names for the createQuery call, in hopes I was Doing It Wrong(TM) but no luck so far. This problem really has me stumped, has anyone come across something similar before?

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:341)
    at $Proxy12.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.package.mvcfromscratch.dao.PostgresEventDao.numberOfEvents(PostgresEventDao.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy11.numberOfEvents(Unknown Source)
    at com.package.mvcfromscratch.main.UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:27)
```

Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.package:mvcFromScratch:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jpa:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.3-Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.3-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.3-Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.3-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.9.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.4-702.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.8:compile
```

PostgreSql database:

```
diarmaid=# \d Event;
                                       Table "public.event"
    Column     |          Type          |                        Modifiers                        
---------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 eventid       | integer                | not null default nextval('event_eventid_seq'::regclass)
 eventname     | character varying(255) | 
 eventdate     | character varying(255) | 
 eventcapacity | bigint                 | 
Indexes:
    "event_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (eventid)
```

UserInterface class:

```
public class UserInterface {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml");
        EventDao eventDao = applicationContext.getBean("eventDao", EventDao.class);

        // Are there any events?
        System.out.println("Events: " + eventDao.numberOfEvents());
        // Get all events
        List<Event> listEvents = eventDao.getAllEvents();
        // & Print them all out.
        for(Event event : listEvents) {
            System.out.println(event);
        }
        System.out.println(eventDao.getEvent(2));
    }

}
```

PostgresEventDao class:

```
public class PostgresEventDao extends JpaDaoSupport implements EventDao {

    @Override
    public String numberOfEvents() {
        return (String) getJpaTemplate()
            .getEntityManagerFactory()
            .createEntityManager()
            .createQuery("select count(ev.id) from Event ev")
            .getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Event> getAllEvents() {
        return getJpaTemplate().find("from Event");
    }

    @Override
    public Event getEvent(long id) {
        return (Event) getJpaTemplate()
            .getEntityManagerFactory()
            .createEntityManager()
            .createQuery("select d from Event d where d.id = " + id)
            .getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void setAllEvents(List<Event> listEvent) {
        for(Event event : listEvent) {
            getJpaTemplate().persist(event);
        }

    }

}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="Events">
        <class>com.package.mvcfromscratch.entities.Event</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
                value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/diarmaid" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username"
                value="diarmaid" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"
                value="sqlol" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And finally, applicationcontext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="eventDao" class="com.package.mvcfromscratch.dao.PostgresEventDao"
        autowire="byType">
        <property name="jpaTemplate" ref="jpaTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Events" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Also, I'm running this within eclipse as Run->As Java Application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You included old version of `hibernate-commons-annotations`, which transitively included JPA 1.0, which conflicts with JPA 2.0 required by Hibernate 3.5.

Moreover, since Hibernate 3.5 you don't need to include multiple Hibernate artifacts anymore. You only need to declare `hibernate-entitymanager` in `pom.xml`, it should be enough for your setup.

**See also:**

- [Hibernate Compatibility Matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix)

Comment: Thanks - solved it straight away. I removed all dependencies for hibernate bar the entitymanager, and it ran. Different error message now, but completely unrelated - just my bad coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about this code line in `org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl`:

```
private javax.persistence.LockModeType jpaLockMode
   = javax.persistence.LockModeType.NONE;
```

Since `javax.persistence.LockModeType.NONE` is new in JPA2, I suspect you also have JPA1 on your classpath somewhere. Find and remove it.

Comment: As axtavt suggested, I was including an old version of hibernate-commons-annotations. This did include JPA1 which was my problem. Thanks for the input =)