# 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' while using the JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I am getting the following error while trying out this [JPA tutorial](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started):

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:272)
    at entity.PersonTest.insertAndRetrieve(PersonTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is my **persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="examplePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>entity.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa_test" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Person.java**

```
   package entity;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity 
    public class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private char middleInitial;
        private String lastName;
        private String streetAddress1;
        private String streetAddress2;
        private String city;
        private String state;
        private String zip;

    .
    .
    .
    (getters and setters)
```

Part of my JUnit Test file:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void insertAndRetrieve() {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(p1);
        em.persist(p2);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        final List<Person> list = em.createQuery("select p from Person p")
                .getResultList();
        System.out.println("here...");

        assertEquals(2, list.size());
```

I am using MySQL db, the 'person' table is present in the database. And after

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(p1);
em.persist(p2);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**I can see the two records are inserted in the person table. But on the next statement, it fails.**

**EDIT 1:** 
JARs in my build path:

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar, 
commons-collections-3.1.jar, 
dom4j-1.6.1.jar, hibernate3.jar, 
hibernate-annotations-3.5.5-Final.jar, 
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar, 
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.5-Final.jar, 
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.5-Final-sources.jar, 
javaee-api-5.0-3.jar, 
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar, 
log4j-1.2.12.jar, 
mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar, 
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, 
slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar, 
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0-CR-1.jar
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: With `@Entity` you don't need to declare entities in persistence.xml. The tutorial you're using looks _awful_. May I suggest the official (and top-notch) [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html) instead?

Comment: @Matt Ball: I tried again after removing. Still the same error.

Comment: What libraries/JARs are present in the runtime classpath?

Comment: I imagine you have JPA 1 and JPA 2 implementations on your classpath.  This would give this error.

Comment: @Dave: can you be more specific on how should I get ride of JPA 1.0? As Vineet suggested, I removed ejb3-persistence.jar from build path and I have also included latest version of `hibernate-commons-annotations.jar` (65kb). What else I need to do? (I have mentioned the included jars at the end of the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ejb3-persistence.jar JAR file from the class path. It contains the interfaces of the JPA 1.0 specification. You'll need to retain the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0-CR-1.jar JAR file, for it contains the interfaces for the JPA 2.0 specification.

Note: If you need to work against JPA 1.0, then do not use Hibernate 3.5.5 for it contains the JPA 2.0 implementation. In the future, use Maven for dependency management; it will help you avoid these issues.

**Addendum:**

If I were to setup Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.5 (JPA 2) from scratch, these would be the files I would consider. The following list has been inferred from [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#d0e215) :

- hibernate3.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar and either of

  - cglib-2.2.jar, or
  - javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar

The last two haven't been mentioned in the documentation, but are required. I don't see the need for any of the other JARs, except for mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar and log4j-1.2.12.jar (both of which could be retained).

Comment: You might want to take a look at the updated post. Honestly, I'm not sure how you ended up with that list of JARs in the first place.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. In the future, I would suggest looking at the official Hibernate documentation, or the Java EE 6 tutorial pointed in one of the comments above. As far as setup of Hibernate and JPA is concerned, I would suggesting using Maven, or to use a consistent set of JARs from **only one release** (Maven automatically does this for you).

Comment: It's great that you offered the solution (use **this** classpath).  But what's the *explanation*?  Why did this opaque error occur, and why does changing the classpath allow the problem to be avoided?

Comment: @Cheeso, there's a reason why I linked to the Hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having a similar issue to this:

["java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE" in hibernate with Spring 3, maven, JPA, c3p0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727463/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-none-in-hibernate-with-spring-3-maven-jpa-c3p0)