# Spring Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-aop

First 2 Parts Solved --- I still Got Another Error Below >>>>

I am having trouble w. this Struts - Spring - Hibernate Application.
I got the error while accessing the Action class on Struts. It failed during instantion of the ActionClass due to Spring failed to create a Hibernate object bean.

Then I used log4j to get the info. It complained about :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [factory/bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [factory/bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
```

Here is the full log4j log on the console :pastebin/z6FFAUEE

Here is my bean.xml : pastebin.com/nREBZ99N

I am honestly not very sure what the error is about, because this is my first time using Spring Hibernate and also the AOP aspects.
I think I have all the libs needed, but I am not very sure too. I think it could be on the xml setting or some missing parameters.

Any helps / pointers is appreciated.
Thx

^^^^SOLVED -- Now I got another error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
```

this is probably another library issue : Google Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V

but i m not again vr sure since, I am new using this framework, I am not vr familiar / knowledgable.

Any help poiting out the error/cause would sincerely be appreciated.
There is a ton of libs jars and I am only familiar with few of them, mostly just guessing the others. The libs is inherited from other application. Any links on good reference on libs also appreciated.

Here they are : http://pastebin.com/tgz8UFfs

^^^^SOLVED - Solution : I removed the text files from lib.

I had this error now, complaining that: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer

It complains about error on creating serviceProxyTemplate .. etc cannot initiate ^ class
here is the full stack trace : http://pastebin.com/c7rqk5cR

What library is the error / what lib do I need ?

Thx for the help

Comment: Please show your Spring and Hibernate configuration as well as your dependencies

Comment: Possibly a classpath/jar issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295389/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-while-using-the-jpa

Comment: Got the answer. Google : Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIBERNATE. Thanks all

Comment: Don't continually change your question. Once one clearly-defined issue is resolved, accept an answer and post a new one.

Comment: ^Ok. I solved this too. Basically the libs are all fine, and basically I just need to remove the tmp text file. I cloberred up the lib, I just re-imported the whole lib from prev application and remove the empty tmp file. Although I m still not sure of all the icky libs as of this time. But thanks all.