# Hiberante + Struts + Spring Security : Tomcat server not starting : Context Initialization Failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, spring-security, pom.xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE” in hibernate with Spring 3, maven, JPA, c3p0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727463/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-none-in-hibernate-with-spring-3-maven-jpa-c3p0)

I am trying a integration of Struts2 + Spring Security3.1.1 + Hibernate 4.1.1

While starting my tomcat server I am getting the following error:

```
    09 Nov 2012 11:06:52 ERROR context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:649)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
9 Nov, 2012 11:06:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:649)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
9 Nov, 2012 11:06:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
9 Nov, 2012 11:06:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/PayPilotWeb] startup failed due to previous errors
9 Nov, 2012 11:06:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:commons-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<display-name> Web Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

<debug />
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<http pattern="/styles/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/login.html*" security="none" />
<http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <form-login login-page='/login.html' default-target-url='/about.html' always-use-default-target='false' authentication-failure-url="/login.html?failed=true"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <http-basic />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.html">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html?logout=true" logout-url="/logout.html" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSION" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="deniedAccessHandler" />

</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
             <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0">
        <util:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
        </util:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>  
<beans:bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">

    <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.impl.UserServiceImpl" />
```

commons-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"


xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<import resource="classpath:security.xml" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.web" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">           
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:commons.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="com.PasswordEncryptor" />
<!-- Database and Hibernate Configuration %Starts-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${app.db.driverclass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${app.db.jdbcurl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${app.db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${app.db.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.dao.ABC</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${app.db.dailect}</prop>
            <prop key="initialSize">5</prop>
            <prop key="maxActive">${app.db.maxpoolsize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/> 
</bean> 
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="mySessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>abc</name>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.0</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.struts-version>2.3.4</org.struts-version>
        <hibernate.jpa.version>2.0-cr-1</hibernate.jpa.version>
        <org.hibernate-version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
            <!-- will come with Hibernate core -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2-pre4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <classifier/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.struts-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.struts-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.struts-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Please help me guys.
Let me know if you need any more details from me.

Comment: It seems jars mismatch.. Check once.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727463/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-none-in-hibernate-with-spring-3-maven-jpa-c3p0

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary I have done same hibernate configuration as suggested in the solution of above question.I think its something related to spring-security configuration. Some jar need to be excluded(most probably spring-core)

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary I have added my pom.xml, please verify.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a constant

```
<org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

and use it for some of the Spring dependencies, still you defined some of them with different version:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It is asking for troubles.

You also use Hibernate-Spring components from 2 different versions:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/> 
</bean> 
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="mySessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Look at the packages:

`hibernate3` and `hibernate4`.

You defined constant:

```
<org.hibernate-version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
```

but still hardcode your Hibernate version:

```
 4.1.1.Final
```

Also note that Spring Security 3.1.X uses Spring 3.0.X 
Take a look at the versions of the jars at your classpath.

Make sure you only have one version of Spring at your classpath.

Comment: THanks for pointing out the mistakes, but I solved this question by exluding spring-core dependencies in spring-security

Comment: I pointed that out - `Also note that Spring Security 3.1.X uses Spring 3.0.X Take a look at the versions of the jars at your classpath.`